# Matlab - Most repeated values in array (not just mode)

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array with numbers that range from 1 to 4. I need to know which is/are the values that repeat more. In case there's a draw I need to know which are the values so I can make some operations.

**Example:**

```
a = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4]
Output = [1 2]

a = [1 1 1 2 3 4]
Output = 1

a = [1 2 2 3 3 4 4]
Output = [2 3 4]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your input `a` always sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
a = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4];
values = [1 2 3 4];

counts = zeros(1,numel(values));

for i=1:numel(values)
    counts(i) = sum(a == values(i));
end

output = values(counts == max(counts));
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternate vectorised approach using `hist` and `unique`

```
uVal = unique(a);
counts = hist(a,uVal);
out = uVal(counts == max(counts));
```

Results:

```
a = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4];

>> out

out =

 1     2
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the input row vector is already sorted (otherwise you can sort it with a call to [`sort()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)), you can use an approach based on `find`, `diff` & `max` -

```
%// Find starting indices of each island of identical numbers being
%// appended by the numel()+1 with the intention of getting island lengths
%// later on by differentiating along the indices
start_ind = [0 find(diff(a)) numel(a)]+1
lengths = diff(start_ind)

%// Look for the islands with the max island lengths. 
%// Use those to get unique numbers associated with them for final output
out = a(start_ind([lengths == max(lengths) false]))
```

---

### Benchmarking

Here's a benchmarking test to compare runtimes for the four solution approaches listed so far -

```
a = randi(10000,1,1000000);

disp('---------------- With for-loop')
tic
values = unique(a);
counts = zeros(1,numel(values));
for i=1:numel(values)
    counts(i) = sum(a == values(i));
end
output = values(counts == max(counts));
toc
clear output counts values

disp('---------------- With find+diff+max')
tic
sa = sort(a);
start_ind = [0 find(diff(sa)) numel(sa)]+1;
lengths = diff(start_ind);
out = sa(start_ind([lengths == max(lengths) false]));
toc
clear out lengths start_ind sa

disp('---------------- With mod')
tic
[~, ~, v] = mode(a);
result = v{1};
toc
clear v result

disp('---------------- With unique+hist+max')
tic
uVal = unique(a);
counts = hist(a,uVal);
out = uVal(counts == max(counts));
toc
```

Runtimes -

```
---------------- With for-loop
Elapsed time is 32.879074 seconds.
---------------- With find+diff+max
Elapsed time is 0.077948 seconds.
---------------- With mod
Elapsed time is 0.136005 seconds.
---------------- With unique+hist+max
Elapsed time is 0.250994 seconds.
```

Comment: Hehehehe, love the fact that the `for` loop took the longest. +1.

Answer (score 4):

The third output of [`mode`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html) gives just that. The input vector doesn't need to be sorted.

```
[~, ~, v] = mode(a);
result = v{1};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) combined with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
[vals,~,id] = unique(a);
b = accumarray(id, 1);
result = vals(b == max(b));
```